# Are there aircraft exemptions for CPDLC in the NAT area?

Tags: avionics, cpdlc, nat

[Another question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/which-airplanes-are-exempt-from-europes-2015-cpdlc-link-2000-requirement) lists the aircraft that are exempt from the EASA CPDLC rule.

Is there a similar exemption for aircraft operating in the North Atlantic?

Comment: I think there is no exemption possible. But not all tracks and levels are covered by the NAT CPDLC rules.

Comment: @DeltaLima Not all tracks yet, but next year they will be and all NAT airspace in 2017.

Comment: Looks like it indeed. You'll have to fly below FL350 or above FL390. Climbing through the FL350-390 block seems to be possible for unequipped aircraft.

Comment: Or fly through the ADS-B corridor from Canada to Iceland. There is no datalink mandate in surveillance airspace  apparently.

Answer (score 3):

There will be no exemptions for the CPDLC rule in the North Atlantic Track area.

The Datalink Mandate will be implemented:

- starting 5 February 2015: FL350 to FL390 (inclusive) on all tracks within
  the NAT Organized Track System (OTS)
- starting 7 December 2017: FL350 to FL390 (inclusive) throughout the ICAO
  NAT region.
- starting 30 January 2020: FL290 and above throughout the ICAO NAT region.

ATS Surveillance Airspace, airspace north of 80°N and the New York FIR are excluded from the mandate. 
This means that aircraft equipped with a suitable transponder / ADS-B transmitter will be able to cross using the Canada - Greenland - Iceland ADS-B corridor without having to carry FANS 1/A equipment.

[image]